# Can't add project user as PR reviewer

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

In Azure DevOps, I'm trying to add a user as required reviewer on a PR, but I get this message:

> The reviewer 'reviewer_name' does not have permission to view this pull request

I can see that they are a contributor, and have the same repo permissions as I do

What can I check to ensure they have the correct permissions set up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can see that they are a contributor, and have the same repo permissions as I do

According to your description, these users should only have stakeholder access.

Actually, to contribute a pull request you need be qualified with two things:  **Permission** ,  **Access Level**.

[image]

**User with Stakeholder access level, he will not be able to use Azure Repos for your private project.**

Of cause he is also not able to view any pull request in Azure Repos.

You could check this info from Organization Setting-- Users--Access Level

[image]

For more detail concept you could refer our official link:  **[Get started as a Stakeholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/get-started-stakeholder?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)**

Please change the user access level to Basic and above, then this user should be able to see and access these repos and view pull request.

**Note:** To change access level, you must have Project Collection Administrator or organization Owner permissions in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

The Permissions required to perform Pull Request must be Contribute/Contribute to Pull requests, asfound at: [Set Repository Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#git-repository)

This can be set > Project Settings > Repository > Target Group > Access Control Summary screen.

Check the permissions at the repo level, since it has to set in the Repo.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems the user needed to have at least 'basic' access at organisation level

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am glad it resolved your issue. If you think the answer was helpful, please "Accept as Answer".

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because that particular user was set as a **Stakeholder** at the **Organisation Level**

Even though they were a project administrator, I had to upgrde their organisation permissions to **Basic** access

[image]

[image: - Users]

[image]